# Java Android ScrollView buttons always at the top

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a ScrollView  and inside I have a LinearLayout and inside I have a buttons. I don't know how I can have this buttons always at the top when I scroll a view. Now when I scroll view a buttons disappear.

My code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:weightSum="1">    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
                    <Button 
                        android:id="@+id/cpic"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Zdjęcie" />    
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/up"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Wyślij" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Imageprev"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />  
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: move the linear layout above scroll view and place the scrollview below the button layout using `android:layout_below` attribute

Comment: @Krzysztof Pokrywka: Keep your button out of <ScrollView> i.e, it should be direct child of <RelativeLayout>

Comment: @SaravInfern Thanks for help ! It work

Answer (score 3):

what I understand from your question i think you can achieve it by putting your button outside your scroll view inside XML , this would give you a fix button.

hope this helps.

Comment: this could be a comment, try adding code samples when you are answering

Comment: i cannot put comment because of my lack of rep ... :(